# Passing data to another view using a model - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to pass the data retrieved from the API to a View, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Class 'ApiManagerViewModel' has no initializers
```

This is how the ViewModel looks:

```
class ApiManagerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var blockchainData: ApiDataClass
    
    func callAPI() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "myapiurl") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        
        let callAPI = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, responce, error in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponce.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // update our UI
                        self.blockchainData = (decodedResponse.data)
                    }
                    // Everything is good, so we can exit
                    return
                }
            } catch {
                print("Unexpected error while fetchign API: \(error).")
                return
            }
        }
        callAPI.resume()
    }
```

This is the model:

```
// MARK: - APIResponce
struct APIResponce: Codable {
    let data: ApiDataClass
    let error: Bool
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct ApiDataClass: Codable {
    let address, quote_currency: String
    let chain_id: Int
    let items: [ApiItems]
}

// MARK: - Item
struct ApiItems: Codable {
    let contract_decimals: Int32
    let contract_name, contract_ticker_symbol, contract_address, logo_url, type, balance: String
    let supports_erc: [String]?
    let quote_rate: Double?
    let quote: Double
}
```

I've tried initializing it but it's no bueno:

```
init() {
        let address = 0, quote_currency = 0
        let chain_id = 0
        let items: [ApiItems]
    }
```

If I initialize it like that I get the error, and I also don't want to repeat the same thing the model has:

```
Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
```

I also tried with the variable like:

```
@Published var blockchainData = []
```

and I get the error on this line: `self.blockchainData = (decodedResponse.data)`:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'ApiDataClass' to type '[Any]'
```

How can I make the variable `blockchainData` have the value coming from decodedResponse.data so I can pass it to another view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because you've declared `var blockchainData: ApiDataClass`, but haven't given it an initial value (your attempt at providing an initializer for `ApiDataClass` didn't help because the problem is `ApiManagerViewModel`).

The easiest solution to this is to turn it into an optional:

```
@Published var blockchainData: ApiDataClass?
```

Then, in your `View`, you'll probably want to check if it's available. Something like:

```
if let blockchainData = viewModel.blockchainData {
  //code that depends on blockchainData
}
```

(assuming your instance of `ApiManagerViewModel` is called `viewModel`)

Comment: Oh man, I thought I tried that too, I guess it's too late at night :)
Thank you